# Encountering a Syntax Error while attempting to blit an image in Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface, blit

I am encountering a syntax error after I blit an image on my display window. I made a separate module where inside of it, I created a class that would manage all the aspects(position, behaviour) of the image. I loaded the image and fetched its rect and finally I drew the image in it's desired position. The file had no errors and so I shifted to the main file that managed game assets and behaviours. In the main file, I imported the class that managed the image. Then, I made a call(after filling the background) to draw the image so it appears on top of the background. It gave me the error

**line 46
    self.ship.blitme()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Here's the code snippet to the image class

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""

        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""

        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Here's the main class for managing game assets and behaviour

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()


        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        # Set the background color.
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""

        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_events()


            # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.

    def _check_events(self):
        # Respond for keyboard and mouse events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()


    def _update_events(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill((self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()


        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a closing bracket in line 45, `main.py`:

```
self.screen.fill((self.settings.bg_color) ) # <-- this one
```

Unfortunately, Python often marks a line beneath the wrong one.

Comment: wow! All this time and it was just a closing bracket haha. Thank You !!!